# Slow saving to Django database

Tags: python, django, performance, sqlite, django-queryset

I have created a custom `manage.py` command like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from photos.models import Person


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Pre-populate database with initial data'

    def _create_people(self, user):
        for i in range(0, 100):
            person = Person(first_name='FN', surname='SN', added_by=user)
            person.save()

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        user = User.objects.get(username="user1")
        self._create_people(user)
```

I've timed the `handle()` execution, it takes about 0.02 s if I don't do `person.save()` and about 0.1 s per `Person` if I do save. The database is sqlite, I believe it should be way faster. What could explain such poor performance and how can I improve it?

Comment: This is a non issue. A command that runs just once taking 0.02 is not something to spend even a second of your time on.

Comment: @e4c5,  agree, but it doesn't.  It takes 0.1 s per entry, so 5 minutes for 3000 entries. And that's just one model.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Analysis:**

```
def _create_people(self, user):
   for i in range(0, 100):
     person = Person(first_name='FN', surname='SN', added_by=user)
     # Hits the database for each save.
     person.save()
```

This function will hit the Database 100 times and auto-commits each time, and this is what is causing the low performance (without considering the low performance of sqlite in comparison with MySQL or PostgreSQL).

**Improvement:**

What you need here in your case is [`bulk_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) which takes as input an array of objects created using the **class constructor**. So a possible solution is as follow:

```py
def _create_people(self, user):
   person_data = {"first_name": "FN", "surname":"SN", "added_by": user}
   person_list = [Person(**person_data) for i in range(100)]
   Person.objects.bulk_create(person_list)
```

> By default `bulk_create` hits the DB once no matter how many objects, except in SQLite (In SQLite it's about 999 per query.).
>       How many objects can be created in a single query can be specified through
>       the parameter `batch_size`.

**NB:**

> - save() will not be called, and the related signals will not be sent.
> - does not work with m2m relationships.

Comment: bulk_create is the way to go +1

Comment: Awesome. I've had to modify the code a tiny bit, because I think bulk_create requires a list of model objects, not input data. So the change to `person_list.append(Person(first_name='FN', surname='SN', added_by=user)); Person.objects.bulk_create(person_list)` has solved the problem (getting `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'pk'`).

Comment: @texnic you are right, It was a typo, I did not notice that (y)
Answer updated ;)

Comment: Huge improvement in performance. Just a modification as texnic mentioned. "bulk_create requires a list of model objects"